# Do not receive echo-reply from ping request with scapy

Tags: macos, request, ping, scapy, reply

I use scapy and try to make a ping and receive the reply.

`my_ping = Ether() / IP(dst='8.8.8.8') / ICMP()
rep,no_rep = srp(my_ping)`

The problem is that I don't receive any answer. The ping 8.8.8.8 works well using the terminal.
I've this problem on my Mac (OS X 10.10 Yosemite) and also on the Ubuntu VM installed on my Mac. However, those commands work on my AWS Ubuntu machine.

If somebody has a clue... feel free to answer

Comment: Do you receive a reply when executing `ping 8.8.8.8` from the command line? Do you receive a reply via Scapy when replacing the IP address `8.8.8.8` with the IP address of the Ubuntu VM?

Comment: Like I said, the ping request works from the command line. I do not receive any reply when I replace `8.8.8.8` by the local IP address or `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Perhaps the firewall is configured to block incoming/outgoing ICMP packets?

Comment: But it works with the terminal. So that's why it doesn't make sense, isn't it ?

Comment: Oh, does the ping command work using the terminal on both machines (i.e. on the Mac and on the VM installed upon it)?

Comment: You mean `ping 8.8.8.8` ? If it's the case, the answer if yes.